# How to force Xcode to run a Run Script in Build Phases

Tags: ios, xcode

We have a Run Script (above compile sources) that is supposed to fire every time we try to build. This has been working for a long time, until we added a path to the "Output Files"-list (below the actual script code) for external reasons. When doing this, Xcode seems to decide for itself whether or not to run the script before every build. I think it checks if the file at the output path exists, and has some internal logic based on e.g "createdDate" or "modifiedDate" to evaluate whether to run it or not.

I need this script to run EVERY time. Even if it was fired 3 seconds ago. Is there a way to force it to run every time?

I tried adding a "Run Script" before the relevant script, which just had "rm -rf outputPath", but somehow it still skips it.

Comment: https://indiestack.com/2014/12/speeding-up-custom-script-phases/ It may have changed since then, but that's a good start, no? Like "Lack of modification to any of the listed input files encourages Xcode not to run the script phase. Hooray! Fastness!" might be a start for search. If you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in question was a part of Apollo's GraphQL stuff. It takes a bunch of .graphql-files in our project and converts them into/generates a API.swift-file for us to use. We had to add the path of the output file to "Output Files" in the script, due to some external CI stuff. This is what cause the script to be ignored sometimes, because Xcode deemed the previously generated file as "good enough", thus not generating it again, even though the content of the .graphql-files had changed in the meantime.

I solved it by adding the paths to all the folders containing all our .graphql-files to an .xcfilelist, and adding it in the "Input File Lists" above "Output File". This forces Xcode to check whether these files have been altered every time we build, and just regenerating when necessary.

This turned out way better than it originally was (regenerated every single time, even though it was just a few seconds to generate).
I can recommend everyone who uses Apollo/GraphQL to do the same.

Comment: Not sure, why this has been downvoted to -1. The correct solution is exactly as described by Sti. This also works with the new Xcode build system (since Xcode 10). So, I added a +1.  
It should be noted, that if the dependencies are not specified for the code generator, the Run Script runs in parallel with other dependencies of the main binary, which then can result in race conditions where the final binary may be incorrect.